# Ansible Variable in lookup syntax

Tags: ansible

I am currently using a `k8s` lookup to search for resources with a certain tag attached to them (in this case `branch`). This `branch` is a variable that changes regularly. The problem is that I can't seem to find the correct syntax for adding a variable into the `lookup` since it is itself using the Jinja syntax.

This works:

```
  - name: delete the replicaset
    k8s:
      state: absent
      api_version: v1
      kind: ReplicaSet
      namespace: default
      name: "{{ replicaset.metadata.name }}"
      kubeconfig: /var/lib/awx/.kube/config
    vars:
      replicaset: "{{ lookup('k8s', kind='ReplicaSet', namespace='default', label_selector='branch=testing' ) }}"
```

However, when trying to use the `branch` variable, nothing I try seems to work. Here is one example of not working:

```
  - name: delete the replicaset
    k8s:
      state: absent
      api_version: v1
      kind: ReplicaSet
      namespace: default
      name: "{{ replicaset.metadata.name }}"
      kubeconfig: /var/lib/awx/.kube/config
    vars:
      replicaset: "{{ lookup('k8s', kind='ReplicaSet', namespace='default', label_selector='branch={{ branch }}' ) }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add a helper variable:

```
- name: delete the replicaset
  k8s:
    state: absent
    api_version: v1
    kind: ReplicaSet
    namespace: default
    name: "{{ replicaset.metadata.name }}"
    kubeconfig: /var/lib/awx/.kube/config
  vars:
    replicaset: "{{ lookup('k8s', kind='ReplicaSet', namespace='default', label_selector=my_selector ) }}"
    my_selector: branch={{ branch }}
```

or use a Jinja2 string concatenation:

```
    replicaset: "{{ lookup('k8s', kind='ReplicaSet', namespace='default', label_selector='branch='+branch ) }}"
```

Comment: I keep forgetting this is just Python under the hood. I used the string concatenation and it worked perfectly!